# Does Slant Drilling overwrite an existing ressource?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

Does Slant Drilling overwrite an existing ressource? In the exemple below, will the small water ressource will become a high one instead ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. With slant drilling, a mine/pump/quarry will dig from adjacent tiles if they have a higher amount of the resource.